# How to use random.random() in python

Tags: python

Hello I am working on a problem set and everything has been going well till I got to random.random() the instructions are to  (Use random.random() to print 10 float numbers from from 21.0 to 30.0 inclusive) however what I am stuck on is on printing the 10 float numbers a example is below.

```
e =random.random() * 21.0 <= 30.0
for x in range(2,10):
    print (e)
```

however what it is returning is just "True" "True" if I could get some advice on solving this it would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Because random.random() * 21.0 <= 30.0 produces a boolean value!

Comment: `e = random.random() * 9 + 21` (but place it inside the loop)

Comment: `range(2,10)` is going to do something 8 times. You just want `range(10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import random
>>> for i in range(10):
...   print random.random() * 9 + 21
... 
22.3034067631
26.7803685261
26.8129361915
25.0246844772
23.7558474791
24.9746222797
21.165252633
26.6308193853
29.6625880762
22.3434394977
```